# Serialization в java

Tags: java, сериализация, zip

Создал 2 метода:

1. Пишет 1 и тот же объект несколько раз в 1 и тот же txt файл
2. Пишет 1 и тот же объект несколько раз в 1 и тот же zip файл

Код:

```
private void serializeRepoToTxt(ProductRepository repository) throws IOException {
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("products.txt"))) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                oos.writeObject(repository);
                LOGGER.trace(new File("products.txt").length());
            }
        }
    }

    private void serializeRepoToZip(ProductRepository repository) throws IOException {
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("products.gz")))) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                oos.writeObject(repository);
                LOGGER.trace(new File("products.gz").length());
            }
        }
    }
```

На каждой итерации цикла логгер выводит размер файла, в который поток пишет

Результаты txt ->
1034
1039
1044
1049
1054
1059
1064
1069
1074

Результаты zip ->
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10

Вопрос. Как объяснить полученые резутьтаты?

Comment: Не пробовали закрывать потоки перед тем как замерять размер файлов? что-то типа `oos.close()`?

Answer (score 0):

Вы проверяете размер файла, перед тем как в него реально что либо запишется.

Обычно в таких случаях данные сначала хранятся в памяти, пока поток не достигнет какого либо лимита, или работа с ним не будет завершена, и только потом данные будут записаны в файл.

Например, если это какой нибудь архив со словарем вначале файла, то неизвестно в каком виде данные будут выглядеть окончательно.

Если необходимо немедленно отправить данные в файл, предусматривают метод `flush()`, но даже он, иногда может быть проигнорирован (например случай архива со словарем вначале).

Попробуйте с обычным файлом:

```
private void serializeRepoToTxt(ProductRepository repository) throws IOException {
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("products.txt"))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            oos.writeObject(repository);
            oos.flush(); //Скидываем в файл
            LOGGER.trace(new File("products.txt").length());
        }
        oos.close(); //Скидываем остатки в файл, которых нет
        LOGGER.trace(new File("products.txt").length());
    }
}
```

Не уверен, что с архивом получиться:

```
private void serializeRepoToZip(ProductRepository repository) throws IOException {
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("products.gz")))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            oos.writeObject(repository);

            //Не думаю что с архивом так стоит делать
            //oos.flush(); 
            //LOGGER.trace(new File("products.gz").length());
        }
        oos.close(); //Скидываем все в файл
        LOGGER.trace(new File("products.gz").length());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что по умолчанию используется конструктор [`GZIPOutputStream(out, false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html), где второй параметр указывает на то, что

> `syncFlush` - если `true`, то вызов унаследованного метода `flush()`
>   этого экземпляра сбрасывает компрессор с режимом очистки
>   [`Deflater.SYNC_FLUSH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html#SYNC_FLUSH) перед очисткой выходного потока, в
>   противном случае только очищает выходной поток.

---

этим и объясняются полученные результаты. Попробуйте поменять второй параметр и посмотрите насколько изменится выходной файл, возможно вам также надо облегчить компрессию, иcпользуя уровень компресии [`NO_COMPRESSION`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html#NO_COMPRESSION), чтобы результаты были более наглядными.

---

если даже это не помогает, то попробуйте [`finish()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html#finish()):

> Завершает запись сжатых данных в выходной поток без закрытия базового
>   потока. Используйте этот метод при одновременном применении нескольких
>   фильтров к одному и тому же потоку вывода.

---

используя код:

```
private void serializeRepoToZip(ProductRepository repository) throws IOException {
    try (GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("products.gz")); 
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(gos)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            oos.writeObject(repository);
            gos.finish();
            LOGGER.trace(new File("products.gz").length());
        }
    }
}
```